# How to fix an algorithm that lists 9, 25 and 49 as prime numbers

Tags: c#, methods, primes

This method returns true or false if the number is prime or not. The problem is it shows 9, 25 and 49 as primes numbers. How can I fix it?

```
public static bool IsItPrime(int prime)
{
    if (prime == 2)
        return true;
    else if (prime < 2 || prime % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    else
    {
        int limit = (int)Math.Sqrt(prime);
        for (int i = 2; i < limit; i++)
        {
            if (prime % i == 0)
                return false;                    
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: if (limit * limit == prime) return false;

Comment: If some answer here works for you, you should "accept" it, i.e. click the big green empty check mark next to it.

Answer (score 6):

Change internal loop from

```
for (int i = 2; i < limit; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 2; i <= limit; i++)
```

All the values you're missing are squares of corresponding odd numbers - 3, 5, 7 etc. If you take `(int)Math.Sqrt(prime)` as a limit then you should also check this limit inclusively.

Comment: +1 That should have been obvious due to the numbers that were being falsely reported as prime!

Answer (score 3):

Use `<=` instead of `<` in your loop.  The numbers that are incorrect are squares, and the only other factor is the square root -- but with `<`, you'll never reach it.